# Find max and min values in List[List[String]] comparing by the 1st element in each sub-list

Tags: scala

I have a data structure like `List[(String, List[List[String]])]`. I need to find maximum and minimum value in the `List[List[String]]` comparing the 1st element in each sub-list:

This is how I do it:

```
val timestamp_col_ind = 1

val sorted = processed.map(list => (list._1,list._2.sortWith(_.productElement(timestamp_col_ind).toString.toLong < _.productElement(timestamp_col_ind).toString.toLong)))
```

Then I access maximum and minimum elements using `last.apply(timestamp_col_ind).toString.toLong` and `head.apply(timestamp_col_ind).toString.toLong`, correspondingly.

But the problem is that the sub-lists do not get ordered by the 1st element. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: how is that related to `apache-spark`?

Comment: @TzachZohar: Sorry, indeed this question is just related to scala. It's part of my Spark program, but it definitely does not make sense to have the spark tag. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what a [full example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) solution looks like:

```
// initialise structure
val data = List(("foo", List(List("2", "b", "b"), List("3", "c", "c"), List("1", "a", "a"))))
// sort by long value of first element of sublists
val sortedData = data.map { case (str, lst) => (str, lst.sortBy(_.head.toLong)) }
// get minimum and maximum
val min = sortedData.map { case (str, lst) => (str, lst.head) }
val max = sortedData.map { case (str, lst) => (str, lst.last) }
```

result:

```
min: List[(String, List[String])] = List((foo,List(1, a, a)))
max: List[(String, List[String])] = List((foo,List(3, c, c)))
```

This assumes that the sublists are never empty, i.e. they do have a `head`